# check internet connection on start of the application blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to check whether internet connection is enable on the start of the application and if yes than will move the application ahead else should stop by showing a dialog that internet is not available.

Comment: Try to open a test connection using desired connection methods (BIS, BES, Wifi, WAP, etc) and check if the connection opens successfully.

Comment: hi can u please help me through coding

Comment: this might be helpful for you, http://testberry.blogspot.com/2011/05/blackberry-connectivity-issues.html

Comment: Thnks for your reply but i managed to do it thnks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a connection just to see if it can be done is wasteful of resources and not considered best practice on BlackBerry platforms.

Instead you should use `CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(int coverageType)`

See: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CoverageInfo.html

Comment: ok thnks i understood and did it completely but then too one question is there i m putting it in if and else loop and i want to display dialog of internet available or not but i m showing the error pushmodal exception please help

Comment: Thnks but dont answer i had got the solution

Comment: You really can't just check once. The nature of a BlackBerry (and really any other smart phone) is that the connected state can change at any time.